Minor ImageMagick upgrade on Ubuntu Causes Magick::ImageMagickError in Ruby
After a recent security update to ImageMagick on our Ubuntu server, we started encountering an issue with our Ruby code. We upgraded the ImageMagick package from version 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.3 to 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3ubuntu0.22.04.5. Post-upgrade, the following code began to fail:
require "rvg/rvg"

rvg = Magick::RVG.new(600, 600) do |canvas|
  canvas.background_fill = "white"
  bullets_graphic = ::Magick::Image.read(Rails.root.join("app/assets/images/score_5.png")).first
  canvas.image(bullets_graphic)
end

image = rvg.draw # failure points to this line
image.format = 'jpg'
image.to_blob do |img|
  img.quality = 90
  img.depth = 8
end

We receive the following error:

Magick::ImageMagickError: unable to open image 5335': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2924 [GEM_ROOT]/gems/rmagick-5.5.0/lib/rvg/misc.rb:528:in draw'

The error references this line in the rmagick source code: rmagick/rvg/misc.rb#L528.
Note: If I do not do the canvas.image call, then it works.
Our environment details:
•   Ubuntu Version: 22.04
•   Ruby Version: 3.2.2
•   MiniMagick Version: 4.13.2
•   RMagick Version: 5.5.0

We have tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:
1.  Reinstalled/compiled RMagick

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue after an ImageMagick upgrade? Any suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

Based on a Google search, this error usually indicates a legitimate permission error. Either the input cannot be read or output cannot be written. Perhaps it is trying to write the data to a temporary file that it doesn't have permission to?
